# Non-RESTful HTTP POST with Backbone Model?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, backbone.js

I have been looking at this documentation :

http://backbonejs.org/#Sync

http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#backbones-sync-api

To try and figure out how to make a HTTP POST request to get some JSON data to load into my model. Sadly the web services are not RESTful, so I am doing a POST request, when in fact it should be a GET request. Such is life...

I have ended up with the following result but I am not sure if this is the correct way or if there is an easier way altogether and because I am not strictly using REST pattern I can't seem to find anyway to tie up my services with Backbone pattern.

```
    define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
], function (_, Backbone)
{
    'use strict';

    //model class declaration
    var LocationsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        locations : null, //this stores the json data of buildings and locations

        //url for http post to get location data
        url: '/locations',

        //http request settings
        requestType: 'POST',
        requestContent : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        requestBody: { "lastRefreshedDateTime": "2015-04-01T08:18:06.000+00:00", "uid": "12356789" },
        requestData: 'json',

        /**
         @name constructor
         @method initialise
        **/
        initialize: function (xhr)
        {
            this.doPOST();
        },

        /**
         @name doPOST
         @method doPOST
         @summary uses AJAX HTTP POST to fetch data from EAS
        **/

        doPOST: function ()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: this.requestType,
                data: this.requestBody,
                contentType: this.requestContent,
                dataType: this.requestData,
                url: "http://" + window.location.host + this.url,
                success: function (result)
                {
                    this.locations = result;
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    //TODO - load cached JSON of buildings and locations
                },
            });
        }


    });

    return LocationsModel;

});
```

So this code is essentially

1. Building a POST request with Header information
2. Making the request
3. If success, load the JSON response into the model

Is there anyway I can abstract this more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `.fetch()`:

```
var RestlessModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function(){
        return {
            locations: []
        }
    },
    //url for http post to get location data
    url: '/locations',

    //http request settings
    fetchOverride: {
        type: 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ "lastRefreshedDateTime": "2015-04-01T08:18:06.000+00:00", "uid": "12356789" }),
        dataType: 'json',        
    },
    fetch: function(options){
        options = _.extend(options || {}, this.fetchOverride);
        Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
    }

});
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytdbjof1/) ^^

In case you need to process the request response, override `.parse()`.

Comment: Thanks for this code. I will turn it into a helper class so I can use it for more than one request. What is your thoughts on that?

Comment: I'd need to have look at the bigger picture, nevertheless consider further extension, i.e. `SomeConcreteModel = RestlessModel.extend({ ... })`, so you do not have to rewrite the overrides every time. On top of that, you may want to provide the request `data` via a model function, because I assume it may vary across requests.

Comment: Thanks, just one question. Where does the data get stored after I run model.fetch() 

I checked the model object in the console and cant find my JSON response data?

Comment: In `attributes`, if everything goes right. Single properties are accessible via `get()` as usual.